# Views attachments and filters

Tags: views

I've created a view from geocoded nodes which shows nodes on a map.
I've also created an attachment view which I've attached to this map view.
This is to have a listing under the map view to make items more accessible.

However, I can't get that to work properly e.g. filter properly.
The following describes filters on the map view:

- Content: Geocodes (field_geocodes) - proximity (exposed)
- Content: Date(Exposed Popup date) | Setting
- Content: EventType (exposed)
- Content: Type (= Event)
- Content: Published (Yes)

On the attachment view I checked that it inherits contextual filters and filters. However,

- I'm no aware that is it inheriting filter values e.g. that I need to
  create those filter again in this view?
- Or does inherit whole filtering as is?

Anyhow, attachment results won't filter and shows all from first published node or by changing view settings it won't show anything i.e. filters and there's no results.

Answer (score 0):

if Inherit exposed filters and Inherit contextual filters in Attachment settings is set to Yes then it will inherit filters and it's values